# Would an electric back massager be forceful enough to vibrate bubbles out of concrete in a casting project?

Tags: concrete, tools

I've been watching youtube videos on casting concrete and would love to give it a shot. Thing is, I'm lazy and don't want to whack my form with a hammer for thirty minutes to an hour. I happen to have a back massage, the kind with two bumps that oscillate back and forth like miniature domed hammers (similar to pictured below). Would something like this provide enough force to loosen bubbles in concrete, or would I have to use a hammer to dislodge air pockets?

[image]

Comment: If you're that lazy, why not hire a professional?

Comment: I like it. Why not test it on a small form?